# How to know if my oracle DB is on premise or cloud

Tags: database, oracle, cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db

How to know if my oracle DB (19c) is on premise or running on cloud?
This DB is connected with Apex as well.
I have searched in Google but could not get any solution.

Comment: It's not possible because DBMS knows nothing about what its host is. Cloud instance is the same dedicated database as on premise, but with additional resource management

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
select CLOUD_IDENTITY
from v$pdbs;
```

That will tell if you its on Oracle cloud, or (null) means on-premises.

Comment: I am getting invalid identifier error while trying to select cloud_identity from v$pdbs

Comment: if the column is not present, then you're definitely not cloud.