How to identify if my Oracle DB is on premise or running on DBaaS host?
I have already gone through this link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75680600/how-to-know-if-my-oracle-db-is-on-premise-or-cloud]
but couldn't get any help from the query suggessted as column CLOUD_IDENTITY didn't came in output .
Please guide

This appears to be a duplicate of the question you linked to.  If you are getting an error that the column does not exist, you are not in the cloud.
